# Turning MeeGo into Ubuntu or Lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, lenovo, meego

Practical question:  I have MeeGo pre-installed and working fine on my Lenovo S10. With fresh-installed Lubuntu some devices are not working. I don't like MeeGo interface. If I uninstall it's graphical interface and install LXDE or Ubuntu-package will it work?

Thanks a lot for reading this

Comment: We may be able to give you a better advice if we knew a bit more on the devices that did not work with Lubuntu.

Comment: there are plenty bugs: bluetooth not working, hanging after suspend, can't switch off touchpad, card reader not working.... The netbook came with MeeeGo preinstalled, but I really hate that interface ))

Comment: you may have customized drivers then - not easy (but possible!) to get them working in another distro.

Comment: I believe it will take me a month to learn all that ((

Comment: You can try to install the Ubuntu distribution and use any of the GUIs that it comes with (including LXDE). Or you can try to install a different GUI on the MeeGo distribution. These are completely different approaches; you can't install Ubuntu packages on MeeGo. Note that this site can help you with running Ubuntu on your device, but it can't help you with running LXDE on MeeGo (try [unix.se] for that).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be quite a lot of versions of the Lenovo S10 (I don't own one, so it's hard to comment,) however the [Ubuntu Hardware List](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Lenovo_S10) states that it is supported and works fine, and a search on the forums seem to support this.

I noticed that you picked LUbuntu, I wonder if you could try the vanilla Ubuntu installation- you should be able to get an indication from the liveCD as to whether any of the bugs you mention persist.

Apparently MeeGo uses the rpm package management system, so it would be difficult to simply 'install' any ubuntu interface (which uses apt) on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Meego on my Lenovo S10-2. First things first. If you have meego now you will either have to dual boot it with another distro ubuntu lubuntu etc.

As I have suggested in your other question I would try to test which other one would better suit your pc. I have Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity working fine and dandy on my Lenovo S10-2 (yours might be slightly different to mine) but I have also had Kubuntu netbook edition running on it very well. I have also tested Lubuntu a while ago where it work ok too.

This issue here is not which one but what you want out of it for your netbook.

You cannot install Ubuntu components on top of your meego system but instead could either dual boot it or wipe your Meego off the pc at the Ubuntu install stage.

If you test any of the 'buntu flavours you may find that you have wifi issues but they are more easily resolved with them than in Meego and there is plenty of guidance here if you have Broadcom Drivers ( which I did). (Ubuntu installs these very well for you when you install it)

Meego is based on different architecture I guess to explain it than Ubuntu. So instead of installing .rpm packages you use .deb packages.

So, download a few different flavours and see which one looks better and feels better on your pc. Then if you are ready to change from Meego, back up your data that you want to keep (emails, documents favourites etc) and choose your flavour!

Installing either Ubuntu and or Meego (which I take it you have done already) is quite easy and painless and fast ( abit too fast for people like me who then change from one distro to another!)